# How to Subset Data in R in loop with dates?

Tags: r, loops, subset

I need to subset the precipitation data and do the calculations I require in a loop such that the date will be a window of 60 days.

For example in a code below I am sub setting the data from 2013-08-15 to 2013-10-15.
For next iteration the date will be 2013-10-16 to 2013-12-16 and so on....

```
 # subset 2 months around flood


precip_boulder_AugOct <- boulder_daily_precip %>%
                        filter(DATE >= as.Date('2013-08-15') & DATE <= as.Date('2013-10-15'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here is one way to do it.  You will need to fiddle with the dates: do you actually want 60 days inclusive, 60 days exclusive, or 2 months?

I created a fake dataset to work with that just has `DATE` and `val` columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Parameters
FIRST_INITIAL_DATE <- ymd("2013-08-15")
FINAL_INITIAL_DATE <- ymd("2014-08-15")
RANGE_DAYS <- 60

# Create vector of initial dates (before adding 60 days)
initial_dates <- seq(FIRST_INITIAL_DATE, FINAL_INITIAL_DATE, by = "days")
# Create vector of all dates (beginning with FIRST_INITIAL_DATE, ending with 60 + FINAL_INITIAL_DATE)
all_dates <- c(initial_dates, initial_dates[length(initial_dates)] + 1:RANGE_DAYS)

# Create fake data
boulder_daily_precip <- data.frame(
  DATE = all_dates,
  val = runif(n = length(all_dates))
)

# Obviously you need to change this loop.  Currently `precip_boulder_AugOct` gets overwritten so this represents the last window.
for (date in initial_dates) {
  precip_boulder_AugOct <- boulder_daily_precip %>%
    filter(DATE >= date & DATE <= date + RANGE_DAYS)
}

precip_boulder_AugOct
##          DATE         val
## 1  2014-08-15 0.163611388
## 2  2014-08-16 0.816459793
## 3  2014-08-17 0.859669117
## ...
## 60 2014-10-13 0.514661876
## 61 2014-10-14 0.143665303
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution

You begin to set your start date

```
start <- as.Date('2013-08-15', origin='1970-01-01')
```

Since R will treat this as a double anyway, you can simply add something to it.

```
(end <- start+60)
> [1] "2013-10-14"
```

You can even create vectors with it

```
(timerange <- as.Date(start:end, origin='1970-01-01'))
 [1] "2013-08-15" "2013-08-16" "2013-08-17" "2013-08-18" "2013-08-19" "2013-08-20" "2013-08-21" "2013-08-22" "2013-08-23" "2013-08-24" "2013-08-25" "2013-08-26"
[13] "2013-08-27" "2013-08-28" "2013-08-29" "2013-08-30" "2013-08-31" "2013-09-01" "2013-09-02" "2013-09-03" "2013-09-04" "2013-09-05" "2013-09-06" "2013-09-07"
[25] "2013-09-08" "2013-09-09" "2013-09-10" "2013-09-11" "2013-09-12" "2013-09-13" "2013-09-14" "2013-09-15" "2013-09-16" "2013-09-17" "2013-09-18" "2013-09-19"
[37] "2013-09-20" "2013-09-21" "2013-09-22" "2013-09-23" "2013-09-24" "2013-09-25" "2013-09-26" "2013-09-27" "2013-09-28" "2013-09-29" "2013-09-30" "2013-10-01"
[49] "2013-10-02" "2013-10-03" "2013-10-04" "2013-10-05" "2013-10-06" "2013-10-07" "2013-10-08" "2013-10-09" "2013-10-10" "2013-10-11" "2013-10-12" "2013-10-13"
[61] "2013-10-14"
```

Now you could let you loop run with

```
for(i in seq(0,1000,61)){
  precip_boulder_AugOct <- boulder_daily_precip %>%
    filter(DATE >= as.Date(start+i, origin='1970-01-01') & DATE <= as.Date(start+i+60, origin='1970-01-01'))  
}
```

or whatever loop you like